# How to find out which particular update Windows is downloading?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My system tray is telling me *"windows is downloading updates (9% complete)"*. How do I figure out **what** it is downloading right now? i.e. "KB123456, Flux Capacitor update 2.1c (1.5 MB)" and perhaps monitor progress for a bonus?

The percentage reported isn't changing, or is doing so very slowly. I'm at 90% of our monthly quota and if the download is a big one I'll [pause it](https://superuser.com/questions/564659/is-it-possible-to-pause-the-windows-update-download) until next week. However if it's a small one and just stuck I'll leave it alone (and [fix it](https://superuser.com/a/1022204/16966) later).

Comment: I'm not sure if windows displays this information once you allow the download. You can always stop the download and go back to the list and see the size of the updates and make a decision whether you want to start the download. In case it's set to automatic, you have to go to control panel and set Windows update to manual.

Comment: @Florian, yeah it's on automatic. I'll try turning that off and see what is reported.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes you just have to wait, but if it takes a significantly long time try the following:

- Click the start button and type in services.msc
- Stop the Windows Update Service.
- Delete the contents of the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder
- Start the Windows Update Service.
- Try Windows Update again.

[Source:](https://superuser.com/questions/305576/windows-update-doesnt-progress-beyond-0-kb-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this PowerShell script to get the update status:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The PowerShell script manages updates (download, install, etc). It doesn't report progress on what update is actually downloading.